# What are your experiences developing a web page designed for mobile?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, html

What are some of the pros and cons of developing a web page designed to be viewed on a mobile device? Could it be built to support gestures? What about the performance? Is it close to native or would there be jitters?

Comment: It depends on the requirement of the page. If you just want to display some content then you can use web pages but if your page is interactive then I recommend you to use native design as web page does not support gestures and performance is not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience as an iOS developer, and someone who can do simple web sites:
I recommend doing native apps unless you are on a low budget and don't need functionality like gestures, camera use, etc. There are lots of hybrid apps that actually launch a simple app with a single web browser view. These come at the cost of unexpected layout errors.